# How can i add external configuration files to a c++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, configuration-files

I made a R-type like game using C++, coding with Visual Studio on windows, and I wanted to know if it was possible to add external configuration files to my project: in my main.cpp I am using a lot of methods I created in other classes to put evrything in place for my game. I have a group of methods where i create the patterns of enemies, an other one which allow me to decide when I make them move and collide,etc...

At the moment I have only one level. Now I want to have a config file named for isntance level1, in which i could put all things related to my level, and just read the code in it and proceed in my main...

So, is this possible to do a such a thing? If it is, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Of course reading files is possible in C++!

Comment: There are many tutorials on the web for reading data files in C++ if you don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  You need to decide EXACTLY what data it is that helps you define a level.  Then you need to create a file type (perhaps using a pre-existing formatting like XML or INI) that puts all of your data into those files.  You could have one file per level, or multiple levels in one file.  At that point you can read it in at the beginning of a level, or at some other time.